# JPA @Transient field but it persists

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, transient

I am having difficulty with a field mapped with JPA on a Spring Boot project.
In short, I have a "Request" table that contains a json field called "detail".
This structure is mapped in Java with the @Entity "Request", which contains a "detail" field of the "Detail" class. This class contains several fields that will be shown in various API responses and persisted, but some of them should not be persisted in the database.

To achieve this effect, I tried annotating them with @Transient, but this did not yield the desired result (isLast & isRenewable are saved on the database json column inside request table).

To resolve this, I could certainly create another class that inherits from "Detail" and contains those fields that should not be persisted in the database, and use this class only for the API return value. This approach is feasible, but it seems like a workaround and I would like to find a more elegant solution.

If anyone has any better ideas or sees errors that I may have missed, I would be very grateful.

Below is the code that I am using:

```java
@Slf4j
@Entity
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class Request implements Serializable {

    @Transient public static final GlobalDateFormatter dateFormatter = new GlobalDateFormatter();
    @Transient public String displayName;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2371833240449596686L;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonView(RequestsJSONView.Summary.class)
    private Detail detail;

}
```

```java
@Getter @Setter @AllArgsConstructor
public class Detail implements Serializable {
    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3445021301319058960L;


    @JsonView(RequestsJSONView.Summary.class)
    private String usernameManager;

    @Transient
    @JsonView(RequestsJSONView.Summary.class)
    private Boolean isLast;

    @Transient
    @JsonView(RequestsJSONView.Summary.class)
    private Boolean isRenewable;

    public Boolean getIsLast() {
        return isLast != null && isLast;
    }
    public Boolean getIsRenewable() {
        return isRenewable != null && isRenewable;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "but this did not yield the desired result (isLast, isRenewable)."? The @Transient annotation is the right one for JPA. The field will not be persisted with JPA. If you want to disclose it also from object serialization - use transient keyword instead. BTW: Detail is NOT an entity, no table exists for it.

Comment: my problem is that the fields marked with @Transient are saved on the db

Comment: Got it. You can see the fields 'isLast' and 'isRenewable' in the database column 'detail', but as text representation, right?

Comment: Yes, in the json column

Comment: Please post in the question also your RequestsJSONView class. I will then answer with a solution.

Comment: public class RequestsJSONView {
 public interface Summary {}
}

Answer (score 0):

The annotation `@Transient` is only for JPA entity fields. You are correctly using it for the *displayName* field.

The class `Detail` is not a JPA entity but just a POJO (Plain Old Java Object). There is no need to add `@Transient` here.

This class should be serialized as JSON and persisted in the database column *Request.detail* as text representation. Some of the fields should be omitted however.

You have already a class for configuration of JSON view:

```
public class RequestsJSONView {
    public interface Summary {
    }
}
```

Let us add another interface just for persisted fields:

```
public class RequestsJSONView {
    public interface Persisted {
    }
    public interface Summary extends Persisted {
    }
}
```

The `Detail` class will look like this:

```
@JsonView(RequestsJSONView.Persisted.class)
private String usernameManager;

@JsonView(RequestsJSONView.Summary.class)
private Boolean isLast;

@JsonView(RequestsJSONView.Summary.class)
private Boolean isRenewable;
```

And the entity field will be annotated like this:

```
@JsonView(RequestsJSONView.Persisted.class)
private Detail detail;
```

Comment: It doesn't work as it should, it keeps persisting the data in the db